# Limit number of characters regex

Tags: regex

Trying to figure out a regex which can perform the following

- Can contain alphanumeric characters
- Can contain (-) and/or (/) character
- Must not start with (-) or (/)
- Must not end with (-) or (/)
- Characters (-) and/or (/) cannot be adjacent.
- Total length of the string should be between 3 to 10 characters

What I got with me is the following:

**Edited:**

```
^((([a-zA-Z0-9])*((\/)|(-))?)*[a-zA-Z0-9]$){1,10}
```

I think it able to perform all operations except the last open i.e. Total length should be between 3 to 10 characters.

**Edited:**

Examples:

Match: ENG/14-15 , ENG/14/15 , ENG/2014
No Match: ENG//14-15 (adjacent symbols) , ENG/-14-15 (adjacent symbols) , /ENG/14-15/ (Should not start or end with / or -), ENG/2014-15 (11 Characters)

Can anyone help me out with answer and/or explanation?

Regards

Comment: Can you give some example please ? I don't understand the `{1,9}` and `{1,5}` constraints parts as you did not formulate them

Comment: Sorry @aduch please check the question again, i copied my testing code mistakenly. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*?[\/-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9\/-]{1,8}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Here `(?!.*?[\/-]{2})` is negative lookahead that prevents more than one `/` and `-` together.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oC1vT4/1)

Comment: Excellent @anubhava i tried it for two hours without try to know about negative lookahead but got your answer in less than ten minutes. One more thing can you explain it more in detail if possible.

Comment: [First read here about lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In the demo link there is very good explanation of this regex on right hand side.

Comment: Once you read about it, you can ask any question and I will respond here.

Comment: I thought JavaScript had little support for lookarounds. Has this changed?

Comment: JavaScript supports lookaheads but doesn't support lookbehinds.